# How To Ignore Insets In SwiftUI Form

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to ignore the automatic insets on a SwiftUI form in order to have an image fill the entire width of the screen. I've managed to do so by creating a fake section and adding negative padding, but this seems like a hack. Does anyone have a better suggestion?

[image: Expected result]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form{
                Section(header:
                            Image("stockPhoto1")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(height: 200)
                            .padding(.horizontal, -20)
                            .listRowInsets(.init())
                ){}

                ForEach(0..<5){ section in
                    Section(header: Text("Section \(section)")){
                        ForEach(1..<Int.random(in: 3...8)){ row in
                            Text("Row \(row)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .navigationTitle("Form")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No way, it is Form design. You can use List instead with some of available List styles, eg. GroupedListStyle.

Comment: I tried using a list and it didn't seem to work to well. Can you provide an example?

Comment: If you don't mind the image staying in place and only the form scrolling you can create a VStack with the Image and the form below it.